# Splunk query: how to differentiate max values after regex

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Let's say I have the following chart:
[Input chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YviMg.png)

I'm interested only in the 2nd and 4th fields in the 'version' column (e.g. 22.**180**.0.**2**)
I want to call all events which has:

Maximum value on both 2nd and 4th fields - as "BEST" (in the example: 22.180.1.3)

(NOT max value on 2nd field) AND (Maximum value on 4th field from each one of the values before the AND, for example 170, 160) - as "GOOD" (in the example: 22.170.0.2,22.160.0.3)

All the rest - as "OK".

I've managed to separate the fields using regex, but couldn't do the differentiation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically I want to know if there's an implementation for this kind of command:

|  eventstats max(BTCoreIndex) by BTCoreNumber as maxBTCoreNumber

Comment: What SPL have you tried? What does your data look like?

Comment: Please include the input values as text rather than a screenshot so we can copy them into our test queries.

Comment: So what if you add `22.160.0.4` to your list?  Is `22.180.1.3` still "BEST" ?  I guess what I am asking is if the fourth part is always grouped by the second part?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
| rex field=version "(?<first>[0-9]+)\.(?<second>[0-9]+)\.(?<third>[0-9]+)\.(?<fourth>[0-9]+)"
| eventstats max(second) as max_second,
| eventstats max(fourth) as max_fourth by second
| eval status=if(second=max_second and fourth=max_fourth,"BEST",if(second!=max_second and fourth=max_fourth,"GOOD","OK"))
```

You need two eventstats commands because one of them groups by the second part and the other one doesn't group at all.  I don't think there is any way to do it with one eventstats.

Here is a run-anywhere example:

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="
index version
1     22.180.0.1
2     22.180.0.2
3     22.180.0.3
4     22.170.0.1
5     22.170.0.2
6     22.160.0.1
7     22.160.0.2
8     22.160.0.3
9     22.160.0.4
"
| multikv forceheader=1 fields index version
| table index version
| rex field=version "(?<first>[0-9]+)\.(?<second>[0-9]+)\.(?<third>[0-9]+)\.(?<fourth>[0-9]+)"
| eventstats max(second) as max_second,
| eventstats max(fourth) as max_fourth by second
| eval status=if(second=max_second and fourth=max_fourth,"BEST",if(second!=max_second and fourth=max_fourth,"GOOD","OK"))
| fields - first second third fourth max_first max_second max_third max_fourth
```